# an error with django media and cache

Tags: python, django, image, sorl-thumbnail

I use from [sorl-thumbnail](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

I have a model like this model

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    thumb =  models.ImageField(upload_to='book')
```

and send a book object(that i created in django admin and set a picture into django admin) to my template:

```
{% thumbnail book.thumb "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
   <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

but my page have this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/media/cache/5b/c9/5bc90276a1fb475eb4c28816804e93fa.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

How I can fix this error?

My setting.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

in my urls.py i have:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'media')}),
)
```

and I use from django develope server.

Comment: is file exists in correct path?

Comment: I use from django admin to add a thumb! is not correct?

Comment: i mean is file exists in cache folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this configuration, try this lines
settings.py

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

url.py

```
from django.conf import settings
media_root = getattr(settings, 'MEDIA_ROOT', '/media')    

urlpatterns += patterns('', 
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': media_root})
)
```

Comment: `cache/5b/c9/5bc90276a1fb475eb4c28816804e93fa.jpg` in my directory exist! but page has this error: `GET http://localhost:8000/media/cache/5b/c9/5bc90276a1fb475eb4c28816804e93fa.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND) `

Comment: put simple static file in your media root and check it, for example add simple.css in media and restart your server and check url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/simple.css then tell me about that.

Comment: cache folder doesn't create on media folder.

Comment: which os? what about your permission? your webserver can write in this folder? try: mkdir media/cache && chmod 777 media/cache

Comment: I use from Ubuntu.i think cache folder created by redis(sorl-thumbnail use from redis)

Comment: mkdir media/cache && chmod 777 media/cache

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31461/discussion-between-vahid-chakoshy-and-2-8)